# How do i create a data table mapping the cartId to Purchased item in python?

Tags: python, pandas, mapping, recommendation-engine

So basically, I wanna represent how many items were bought under each cart Id, as a name not as a number. in a 2 columns table.
[this is the first couple of columns for cartid and product name table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTB3E.png)

[this what i am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqS3B.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Also, could you post example data as text, not images?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data.  Copy the text from your editor and paste it into the question, formatted as code.

Comment: The reason why i post the photo, is because i am not sure which function in pandas or anything else, will help me have same output as second table.